# Implement a simple search algorithm

Tags: python

So I am trying to work with the following problem (explanation below):

I have an `array = [4,7,9,10,9,8,8,9,9,9,7,7,6,5]`. These numbers are the 'number of service agents'. The average service level of this array is 0.86 (calculated from an additional function). However, my goal is to reduce the number of agents in this array (one at a time) until I have an improved array with a average service level of closer to 0.8. A condition however is that the number of agents must always stay above a certain threshold value.

Indeed, I have implemented the following code that controls this search algorithm:

```
def optimization_of_agents(list_of_new_agents, vector_of_lambdas):
    search_round = 0
    continue_search = True
    while continue_search:
        index = 0
        service_level_score = 0
        for i in range(len(list_of_new_agents)):
            if list_of_new_agents[i] > vector_of_lambdas[i]/rate_of_service:
                temp_array = list_of_new_agents.copy()
                temp_array[i] = temp_array[i]-1
                temp_service_level = calculate_service_level_optimized_vector(temp_array, vector_of_lambdas)
                if temp_service_level > 0.8 and temp_service_level > service_level_score:
                    service_level_score = temp_service_level
                    index = i
                    print("Search iteration: ", i)
                    print(temp_array)
                    print(service_level_score)
                         
        if service_level_score <= 0.8:
            continue_search = False
        else:    
            list_of_new_agents[index] = list_of_new_agents[index]-1  
            search_round = search_round + 1
            print("\n")
            print("Search After Round: ", search_round)
            print("Improved Vector Of Service Agents: ", list_of_new_agents)
            print("Average Service Level: ", service_level_score)
            print("\n")      

def calculate_service_level(agents, new_lambda):
    N=(((new_lambda/rate_of_service)**agents)/np.math.factorial(agents))
    P=1-(new_lambda/rate_of_service)/agents
    K= sum_agents(agents,new_lambda)
    probability_delay = N / ((P*K)+N)
    service_level = 1-(probability_delay*(np.exp(-(rate_of_service*(agents-(new_lambda/rate_of_service))*0.5))))
    return service_level



def calculate_service_level_optimized_vector(list_of_new_agents, new_vector_lambdas_list):
    service_level_list=[]
    for agents, lambdas in zip(list_of_new_agents, new_vector_lambdas_list):
        new_service_level = calculate_service_level(agents, lambdas)
        service_level_list.append(new_service_level)
    average_array = np.array(service_level_list)
    average = np.mean(average_array)
    #if average > 0.8:
    #print(list_of_new_agents)
    #print(average)
    return average
```

which gives me the following output:

```
Search iteration:  0
[3, 7, 9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6, 5]
0.8485658691850712
Search iteration:  1
[4, 6, 9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6, 5]
0.854410495947378
Search iteration:  2
[4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6, 5]
0.8561148487593274
Search iteration:  3
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6, 5]
0.8568206633443681
Search iteration:  11
[4, 7, 9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8571998848973724


Search After Round:  1
Improved Vector Of Service Agents:  [4, 7, 9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
Average Service Level:  0.8571998848973724


Search iteration:  0
[3, 7, 9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8394202679038497
Search iteration:  1
[4, 6, 9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8452648946661565
Search iteration:  2
[4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.846969247478106
Search iteration:  3
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8476750620631467


Search After Round:  2
Improved Vector Of Service Agents:  [4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
Average Service Level:  0.8476750620631467


Search iteration:  0
[3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8298954450696241
Search iteration:  1
[4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8357400718319309
Search iteration:  2
[4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8374444246438804
Search iteration:  8
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8375936706851099
Search iteration:  9
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8380728605009203


Search After Round:  3
Improved Vector Of Service Agents:  [4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5]
Average Service Level:  0.8380728605009203


Search iteration:  0
[3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8202932435073976
Search iteration:  1
[4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8261378702697044
Search iteration:  2
[4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8278422230816539
Search iteration:  8
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5]
0.8279914691228836
Search iteration:  12
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8280279465736201


Search After Round:  4
Improved Vector Of Service Agents:  [4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
Average Service Level:  0.8280279465736201


Search iteration:  0
[3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8102483295800973
Search iteration:  1
[4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8160929563424041
Search iteration:  2
[4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8177973091543536
Search iteration:  8
[4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8179465551955832


Search After Round:  5
Improved Vector Of Service Agents:  [4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
Average Service Level:  0.8179465551955832


Search iteration:  0
[3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8001669382020605
Search iteration:  1
[4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.8060115649643675
Search iteration:  2
[4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
0.807715917776317


Search After Round:  6
Improved Vector Of Service Agents:  [4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5]
Average Service Level:  0.807715917776317
```

Essentially, my code starts from the first element and changes this value until two conditions are no longer satisfied: 1) average service level of new array is < 0.8 and 2) the new individual element is less than a lambda/mu threshold.

However, I feel this is not great because after changing the first element from 3 to 2 agents, the service level boundary of 0.8 is already reached. This does not seem efficient as it does not allow me to try and reduce the agents in any other portion of the array. So, what I would like to do, is once this level is reached with the new array, go back to the original array I had, and start from the second element and make changes as in the above algorithm (whilst keeping the first element of the original array at 3). But I am unsure how to code this addition.

Hopefully you guys have some tips!

Many thanks, Steve.

Comment: How do you calculate the average service level? (The code in your question should be reproducible, among other things. Without that calculation, we can't reproduce your results.)

Comment: Apologies. I have added this function.

Comment: A brute force approach might be: for each element in the array, temporarily subtract one and check new score, ignoring indexes that have reached their minimum; apply the change that produced the least decrease in score; repeat until you cross your threshold.

Comment: Actually the output now really makes sense. I think I have it!